# Do rupa of God mentioned in satapatha brahmana?

Tags: shatapatha-brahmana

Do satapatha brahmana tells god as rupa
The satapatha brahmana tells Rama and Krishna is avatar of lord

Comment: Please use Google translate from native to English

Comment: Rupa means form of God?